# Is Java EE 6 all for free?

Tags: jakarta-ee, open-source, licensing

I'm just about to start learn some Jave EE6. But in the download page, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-jdk-7u1-downloads-523391.html; it's License Agreement says

"License Rights

We grant you a nonexclusive, nontransferable limited license to use the programs for purposes of developing your applications. If you want to use the programs for any purpose other than as expressly permitted under this agreement you must contact us, or an Oracle reseller, to obtain the appropriate license. We may audit your use of the programs. Program documentation is provided with the programs."

So is there a price for the commercial license? If yes, how much will that be?

Comment: light time down vote, appreciated. But please at least give me an answer.

Comment: It's only free as in beer, not as in freedom ;) (btw. the -1 is not mine)

Comment: So we can deploy commercial website without paying any licensing fee, is that right?

Comment: Yes, you can. I'll repost as an answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about licensing.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing and legal issues, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As the license agreement states , you can use the Java EE SDK to develop any applications.

You also can run and deploy them, expose them to the general public and earn money with them. You might have to to pay for some middleware like the WebSphere AS, but only if you choose to. There are many free alternatives.